# RegEx URL Minor Patten Match Issue regarding '?'

Tags: regex, url, path, segment

All,

Been struggling to not-match a single use case regarding a query (`?`). See below tests matches/non-matches. I dont want to match if the `?` is following the first `/` after hostname segment, but do want match if `?` follows any other path trailing `/`. Regarding language, a JS variant that doesn't require the escapes (`\`).

```
^/(solutions|solucoes|soluciones|oplossingen|losungen)/.+($|\?|\/($|\?))
```

Matches:

```
/solutions/test
/solutions/test/
/solutions/test?param
/solutions/test/?param

/solutions/test/testb
/solutions/test/testb/
/solutions/test/testb/?param
/solutions/test/testb?param

/solutions/?param (match - My problem child, dont want a match here)
```

Non-Matches

```
/solutions
/solutions/
/solutions?
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close here.  After your second slash you need to add a negative lookahead for a question mark.  Negative lookaheads are successful if they do not match what follows, but they also do not move the scan cursor forward, so the characters will be rescanned a second time.

The negative lookahead is `(?!\?)`.  Then I simplified your following code to `.+$` because if you have the /m flag set, $ will match end of line.   Make sure the multi-line flag (/m) is set.

```
^\/(solutions|solucoes|soluciones|oplossingen|losungen)\/(?!\?).+$
```

Here's a screen print of it [in action on Regex101 web site](https://regex101.com/r/iEPLSS/1):
[image]

Comment: Appreciate the answer and insight

Comment: so apparently the system I'm using cant handle the negative lookahead is there an alternate way to write this out? thanks again in advance

Comment: `^\/(solutions|solucoes|soluciones|oplossingen|losungen)\/([^?\n].*)$` seems to work. Similar to The Fourth Bird's answer.

Comment: Thanks for the updates, seems to match my use cases, much appreciated. Just couldn't get this one.

Answer (score 1):

You might exclude matching a question mark after the forward slash by matching a single character other than a newline or question mark using a negated character class.

```
^\/(solutions|solucoes|soluciones|oplossingen|losungen)\/[^\r\n?].*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/olRXLN/1)